# Android capture image and get actual path

Tags: android, ftp, camera, android-camera

I want to create an application that takes picture/video and send it to my FTP server.

Here is my onActivityResult code;

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,final Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PHOTO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Upload sdcard file
        new AsyncTask(){
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                File f = new File(data.getData() + "");
                try {
                    uploadFile(f);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Photo saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (requestCode == VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Upload sdcard file
        new AsyncTask(){
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                File f = new File(data.getData() + "");
                try {
                    uploadFile(f);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Error says no such file or directory. How can I get the actual path of a video or an image taken?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT - EDIT - EDIT

I have used another method to get the path

```
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Now I don't get any error but when I open my ftp folder I cant see the uploaded image :S

Here is my uploadFile method;

```
 public void uploadFile(File fileName) throws IOException {
    SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();
    // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
    ftp.connect(server, port, user, pass);
    // Set binary mode.
    ftp.bin();
    // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
    ftp.cwd("upload");
    // Upload some files.
    ftp.stor(fileName.getAbsoluteFile());
    // Quit from the FTP server.
    ftp.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this code from you activity, see below:

```
if (requestCode == VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    // Upload sdcard file
    new AsyncTask(){
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

            try {

                //Create a empty file what you want...
                File f = new File("Write here your path what you want");

                //Open OutputStream
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                //Write file
                fos.write(data);
                //File is created in your path

                uploadFile(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Tell me if I helped you with this changes and good programming!

Comment: asks me  to surround "FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);" wih try/catch and also "fos.write(data);" cannot resolve method write(android.content.Intent)

Comment: everythings working fine except  fos.write(data); error=cannot resolve method write(android.content.Intent)

Comment: You are use a correct imports? Like this: import java.io.FileOutputStream;

Comment: This method exist, you can verify here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html and i'm using it... You do anything bad... :S

Comment: ofcourse man :) when I type integer like ; fos.write(1); it dont give error but with fos.write(data); there is error

Comment: Nah its string (path of the image) but I've solved the path issue with another method called getPath I've edited my code you can see. NOw ı have other problems tho. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You can't see the image in your device folder?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use getAbsolutePath() from File object it returns path of the file.